# I see my question on "NerdAnswer" is this a problem?

Tags: discussion

Several hours ago I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548965/ubuntu-14-04-opening-spyder-gives-stack-smashing-detected), I did not get an answer, so I kept looking, and found [my question on NerdAnswer](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=763968). I wonder if the they are in a violation of some policies. Just bringing this to moderators attention.

Comment: Why are you asking this question on the stackoverflow meta while your question is on ask ubuntu?

Comment: They appear to be following all of the attribution policies.

Comment: This would actually probably be better on the main http://meta.stackexchange.com, but is still a valid question regardless. If you think they are violating some attribution policies check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers. Otherwise, you'll just have to accept that it's annoying, unfortunately.

Comment: No, I don't think they are following all the rules. The CC license requires that re-users mention that the reused content is under said CC license and link to the CC license (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). This site isn't doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of aggregate sites do things like this. If you think they are violating some [attribution policies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), check out [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers). As animuson points out in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276720/i-see-my-question-on-nerdanswer-is-this-a-problem/276721#comment117028_276720), however, that does not appear to be the case here.

If they aren't violating the policies described in that blog entry (which is also accessible by the licensing link alllll the way at the bottom of every page) then you just kind of have to accept that it's annoying and forget about it, unfortunately.

A lot of search engines are good at pushing these types of sites a little further down on the results pages when possible, so you can often take some comfort in that.